# CSS Grid resizing buttons within grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm going through freecodecamp and trying to make an electronic calculator, still very early on, just trying to get the sizing and layout correct.

I'm using a CSS grid for the buttons but having an issue when I'm trying to resize the buttons.

I have a javascript function that creates a `<button>` element for each button to be displayed on the calculator and then assigns in the corresponding css grid-area property to match the grid.

The layout and function work perfectly, the problem comes when I'm trying to resize the "equals" button, located column 4 and rows 4 and 5.

The button takes up 1 column, but 2 rows of the grid.

As soon as I change the `height` property of the buttons in css, that particular button collapses into 1 column and just 1 row.

Hopefully that makes sense, if not, here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/rorschach1234/pen/gxbbgg

and the html:

```
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet"> 

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="top">Electronic Calculator</h2>
    <div class="display">
      <h2>display</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>
```

the CSS:

```
$calc-font: 'Orbitron';

.container {
  margin: 5% 33%;
  background: grey;
}

.top { 
  font-family: $calc-font;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.display {
  margin: 3% 5%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: $calc-font;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "clearall clearD divide multiply"
    "seven eight nine minus"
    "four five six add"
    "one two three equals"
    "zero zero period equals";    
}

button {
  height: 25px;
}
```

and the javascript:

```
var btnClasses = ["clearall", "clearD", "divide", "multiply", "seven", "eight", "nine", "minus", "four", "five", "six", "add", "one", "two", "three", "equals", "zero", "period"];

var buttons = ["AC", "CE", "&divide;", "&times;", 7, 8, 9, "&minus;", 4, 5, 6, "+", 1, 2, 3, "=", 0, "."];

/*function creates a button and then adds the corresponding grid-area to match the grid-template-areas layout in CSS*/

function createButtons() {
  for (var i = 0; i<btnClasses.length; i++) {
    $(".buttons").append("<button class=\"" + btnClasses[i] + "\">" + buttons[i] + "</button>");
    $("." + btnClasses[i]).css("grid-area", btnClasses[i]);
    $("." + btnClasses[i]).css("font-family", "Orbiton");                          
  };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  createButtons();
});
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of each row in your keypad is defined in the grid container:

```
.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

So there are five explicitly defined rows. They all have the same height, which is an equal distribution of free space in the container.

But when you set a `height` on a grid item it automatically gets `align-self: start`, overriding any `grid-area` sizing you've defined.

*From the spec:*

> [**6.2. Grid Item
>   Sizing**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-item-sizing)
>
> If the grid item has an intrinsic ratio or an intrinsic size in the
>   relevant dimension, the grid item is sized as for `align-self: start`.

If you want the buttons to be 25px tall, and `grid-area` to work, just say that at the container level:

```
.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 25px);
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJGQyj)

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you very much. I guess I didn't fully understand how the grid system sizing worked. I was thinking of it like bootstrap where everything is a fraction / 12. For future reference, would this 'grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 25px);' still work if I decided I didn't want to use the 'grid-template-areas:' way of declaring each row and column space, but instead wanted to use the fractional declaration for each class like: .clearall {grid-column: 1/2; grid-row: 1/2;} ?

Comment: Not sure. A bit too hypothetical. Test it out. Post another question if you get stuck.